# Azure Notification Hub device is registered but not showing in Registration Count (iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to register an iOS device with Azure notification hub(APNS certificate pointing to Production) from my xamarin.ios app.

As expected, on accepting for push notification permission on app launch, the device registers with APNS and calls the "RegisteredForRemoteNotification" method with registered device token.

Here i try to register to my Azure notification hub and the registration succeeds as well

```
var hub = new SBNotificationHub(Settings.notificationHubConnectionString, Settings.notificationHubName);

            hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, new NSSet(ADEmail), err =>
            {

                if (err != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.Description); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully registered with 
                   Notification hub"); 
                }
            });
```

The registered devices list is shown in the visual studio-->ServerExplorer->Notification hub->Device Registrations screen

However the total device count in Apple(APNS) still shows zero. 
[image]

Any idea on why the device count remains 0 will be helpful for me to sort out this issue.Also pushing the notification from notification hub says push was successful but is not received in device.

I'm using an enterprise provisioning profile (in house profile with push notifications enabled) to codesign the app and distribute.

Comment: Hi,  did you test on simulator or physical device?

Comment: i used a physical device to register. iOS version 10.3.3

Comment: @ShriGuru I have the same problem did you get any process ??